# How to map value using lambda in python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following dataframe. I would like to map the value using lambda function to another.

```
S/N 
A
Nan
B
C


Expected:
        S/N
        Apple
        Nan
        Ball
        Cat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a function with your desired conditions, you can achieve it by using apply on the desired column like this.

```
def myfunc(x):
    if x == 'A':
        return 'Apple'
    elif x == 'B':
        return 'Ball'
    elif x == 'C':
        return 'Cat'
    else:
        return x

pd.DataFrame(data=['S/N', 'A', np.NaN, 'B', 'C'])[0].apply(lambda x: myfunc(x))
```

which returns:

```
0      S/N
1    Apple
2      NaN
3     Ball
4      Cat
```

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to answer this question without seeing your full code as there are a lot of ways to map values into data-frames with lambda functions. Here is one example.

Firstly, we use `.apply()` on a data-frame column that we want to draw values from. The apply method will iterate through the data-frame row by row changing the value of the data-frame at that spot based on what the lambda function returns.

In this example the lambda function references a dictionary with stored values in it. The `lambda x` variable represents the value that is currently in the data-frame and the `dict[x]` represents what the lambda function returns/ replaces the data-frame value with.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'S/N': ['A', None, 'B', 'C']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

dict = {'A': 'Apple', None: None, 'B': 'Ball', 'C': 'Cat'}

df['S/N'] = df['S/N'].apply(lambda x: dict[x])
```

Output:

```
    S/N
0   Apple
1   None
2   Ball
3   Cat
```